# PHP Accessing and loading video via samba

Tags: php, video-streaming

I got a pretty specific question. I'm accessing data via samba on distant server and I got no choice. To achieve that in php I use a php wrapper for smbclient from GitHub https://github.com/icewind1991/SMB. I got a piece of code that works to load the video and play it but the problem is that I want to be able to navigate through the timeline and for it to play as soon as there is data to be read.. I repeat that I can't access data any other way and I use that library for other parts of my website so I can't change it. Right now it reads all the data from the whole video before playing it and I can't use the slider to navigate through the timeline. There's my code sample with false authentication data for the samba access.

```
<?php

require('../../class/SMB-master/vendor/autoload.php');

$host = '0.0.0.0';
$user = 'user';
$workgroup = 'workgroup.lan';
$password = 'password';
$share = 'share/'.$_GET["filePath"].'';

$auth = new \Icewind\SMB\BasicAuth($user, $workgroup, $password);
$serverFactory = new \Icewind\SMB\ServerFactory();

$server = $serverFactory->createServer($host, $auth);



$share = $server->getShare($share);

//Reads PDF 4096 bytes by 4096 bytes until there is no more data to read if the format is pdf
if($_GET['openFile'] == 'PDF')
{
    
    $charNumber = 20;
    $result = bin2hex(random_bytes($charNumber));

    header("Content-type:application/pdf");
    header("Content-Disposition:inline;filename=".$result.".pdf");
    
    
    $fh = $share->read($_GET['name']);
    while ($data = fread($fh, 4096))
        echo $data;
    fclose($fh);
    
}
else{
//Reads video 4096 bytes by 4096 bytes until there is no more data to read if the format is video mp4

    header("Content-type:video/mp4");
    header("Content-Disposition:inline;filename=".$_GET['name']."");
    
    $fh = $share->read($_GET['name']);
    while ($data = fread($fh, 4096)){
        echo $data;
    }
    fclose($fh);
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is a samba-realted issue. MP4 format has this weird quirk where the "moov atom", which is a header that contains metadata about video that the player needs in order to play the file, does not have to be at the beginning of the file, and is often at the end, which means the whole file needs to load before it can play. There are tools that can update the file to place the header at the beginning so that players can begin playing as soon as they read in the header, but that's really the only way around this issue.

Comment: Thanks I'll look into that!